# Div opens vertically when page loaded with javascript and css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transition

Im new to web developing and would like to know if there is a way to make the div open vertically without the use of css height transitions. I also to had to add the opacity transition to the div with text since its showing before the main div appears. Here is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/wq7v7/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("body").setAttribute("class","loaded");
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .fadein {
    height: 0px;
    transition: height 0.7s;
    -moz-transition: height 0.7s;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.7s;
    -o-transition: height 0.7s;
    background-color: #39F;
    width: 600px;
    border-top-width: 2px;
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-top-color: #000;
    border-bottom-color: #000;
    }

    #body.loaded .fadein {
        height: 200px;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    .thebox {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    }

    #body.loaded .thebox {
        opacity: 1;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body id="body">


    <div class="fadein">

        <div class="thebox" style="text-align:center; color:#000; font-size:24px; font-family:'Myriad Pro'; margin-top:10px;">

        Choose your city

        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `jQuery` it's simple. And in future don't use some animation on `body`. Use it to inner div. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wq7v7/1/)